# How to check encoding in java?

Tags: java, android

I am facing a problem about encoding.

For example, I have a message in XML, whose format encoding is "UTF-8".

```
 <message>
        <product_name>apple</product_name>
        <price>1.3</price>
        <product_name>orange</product_name>
        <price>1.2</price>
        .......
    </message>
```

Now, this message is supporting multiple languages:

- Traditional Chinese (big5),
- Simple Chinese (gb),
- English (utf-8)

  And it will only change the encoding in specific fields.
  For example (Traditional Chinese),

  蘋果 
          1.3 
          橙
          1.2
          .......

  Only "蘋果" and "橙" are using big5, `"<product_name>"` and `"</product_name>"` are still using utf-8.
  `<price>1.3</price>` and `<price>1.2</price>` are using utf-8.

How do I know which word is using different encoding?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like whoever is providing the XML is providing incorrect XML.  They should be using a consistent encoding.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jchardet/files/ is a pretty good heuristic charset detector.
It's a port of the one used in Firefox to detect the encoding of pages that are missing a charset in content-type or a BOM.

You could use that to try and figure out the encoding for substrings in a malformed XML file if you can't get the provider to fix their output.

Answer (score 1):

you should use only one encoding in one xml file. there are counterparts of the characters of big5 in the UTF_8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Because I cannot get the provider to fix the output, so I should be handle it by myself and I cannot use the extend library in this project.

I only can solve that like this,

```
String str = new String(big5String.getByte("UTF-8"));
```

before display the message.

Comment: It is not a good solution, but I only know this way to solve the problem.
Does anybody has other better solutions?